# Updating table on creating a new row in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these two tables.
 [image]

I am trying to add a new row in the Account table, and then update the AccountId in Client table using the following:

```
public static void AddAccount ()
{
  var db = new DALEntities();
  Account account = new Account();

  db.Account.Add(account);
  db.SaveChanges();
  var newid = account.AccountId;
  if (MySession.Current._ClientId != null)
  {
      Client client = GetClientByID((int) MySession.Current._ClientId);
      client.AccountId = newid;

      db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

I use the following to get the Client:

```
public static Client GetClientByID (int id)
{
    var db = new DALEntities();
    return db.Client.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ClientID == id);
}
```

The new row is added to the Account table, it returns the correct new entry AccountId and the correct Client object; however it does not update the Client table.  I tried to use

```
  db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But got this error:

```
an entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of ientitychangetracker
```

How can I update the Client model before saving it.

Comment: Your database structure doesn't make a whole lot of sense. This is suggesting that an account can belong to more than 1 client, but each client can only have 1 account?

Comment: How does `GetClientByID` work, exactly?  If it's retrieving the `client` using a different db context, it's not going to work.

Comment: You have a cross reference error. Both table referenced each other via Account.Accountid -> Client.AccountId and Client.ClientId -> Account.ClientId so when you save multiple instances error happens

Comment: I see your point, for other parts of the application I need both AccountId and ClientId in both tables.  The accountId belong to one client, and the client can only have one account (to answer the first comment).  Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: I removed the ClientId from Account table and still does not save the AccountId into the Client table.

Comment: Your problem is that your Client is returned from a different instance of DALEntities.  You have to call SaveChanges on the instance that created Client, not the one that didn't.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are instantiating a new DbContext in this context:

```
public static Client GetClientByID (int id)
{
    var db = new DALEntities();
    return db.Client.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ClientID == id);
}
```

In order to make it work you have to make sure that you are getting the two instances from the same context.

Effectively, you will have to make "db" a class level field. Or, for simplicity's sake and to prove that it works, you can make the following change:

```
public static void AddAccount ()
{
  var db = new DALEntities();
  Account account = new Account();

  db.Account.Add(account);
  db.SaveChanges();
  var newid = account.AccountId;
  if (MySession.Current._ClientId != null)
  {
      Client client =  db.Client.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ClientID == id);
      client.AccountId = newid;

      db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Note that DALEntities is not instantiated again. That way it would use the same change tracker.

Hope this helps.